# How can my app users view a lot of images (and possible download them) without me having to rent a server

Tags: android, image, server

So, I now have an app, and the idea is the same as a wallpaper app, a lot of images people can download and use for themselves. There are a little over 200 images in the app right now, but I want to increase this number to a couple of thousand. The problem is, the size of the app will increase very rapidly, so the best idea (I think) is to use some sort of server. Google Photos and Firebase both have quota's, and I know I will reach those both very soon (with only 200 images and the active users I have right now, the limit would be reached very quickly). So, I need another way to let people view the images (my images, I do not just copy them from another site, or any other place online) and be able to download them to their phones, without it costing me money (sorry, Im very poor) or using a service that has a quota. So, I need my android app users to view and download a lot (2500+) of my images, without it costing me money.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go for amazon web services. It's very effective and it's free for a year.after that you have to pay accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud storage is your best bet. This AWS project looks like it would be a good fit for your needs.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/store-your-photos-in-the-cloud-using-amazon-s3/